# Convert String to JSON AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a program that is trying to send a string for example `http//:somewebsite.com` using `POST` to my Lambda function via the AWS API Gateway. I know the API gateway only accepts `JSON` to be sent to Lambda, however, is there a way I can transform the string to `JSON` to be sent to Lambda within the API Gateway?

Comment: Is you string in any specific format? Please share your string along with the question

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan the string is a URL `http//:somewebsite.com` the specific header for the `POST` I am not sure

Comment: I have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to POST just url then please format your json like below,

```js
{"Url" : "http//:somewebsite.com"}
```

Comment: I know this will work but can API gateway convert a string sent to it into JSON to then send to 
lambda

Comment: You cannot string directly to API gateway and data should serialize (JSON, XML etc.) to send it over the wire. As communication to API gateway is using HTTP you should serialize data